# populatin a ListView through network operation. (Multiple threads? or just one?)

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, user-interface, garbage-collection

I'm doing some `HTML` parsing using `Jsoup` and populatin my `ListView` with the parsing results. Now I doubted to myself what would be better. Using multiple `Thread`s (Each one parse other site) or just one `Thread` that will parse from all the sites I use?

The question arises because

**1**:

my `Thread` operation takes a lot of time and suspending all my `Thread`s operation and using the garbage collector often(As the `logcat` says).

**2**:

I want to show the user output as fast as I can(I.E populate the `ListView` as soon i get results).

**3**:

More `Thread`s mean more suspending all `Thread`s warning and `GC` usage, and again a slower output to the user and maybe a "stuck" `UI`.

I'm a little confused about that. I would love to hear what do you think is better for me and why.